# why strcat() is missing some string to concatenation?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have simple program, in which i am taking information and forming record out of them.
if i give the following input:

- name: rahul
- usn: 1rv16is038
- age:20

---

the `strcat()` is missing name string. output should be `1rv16is038|rahul|20|##########` but instead output is `1rv16is038||20|###############`.
why this unusual behavior?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define LEN 30
int main(){
    char record[255],name[30],usn[10],age[5];
    int index;
    printf("\nEnter name: ");
    scanf(" %s",name);
    printf("\nEnter usn: ");
    scanf(" %s",usn);
    printf("\nEnter age: ");
    scanf(" %s",age);
    strcpy(record,usn);
    strcat(record,"|");
    strcat(record,name);
    strcat(record,"|");
    strcat(record,age);
    strcat(record,"|");
    for(int i=strlen(record);i<LEN;i++){
        strcat(record,"#");
    }
    printf("\nRecord created is: %s",record);
    return 0;
 }
```

I have checked that all the variable is taking input, the problem lies in `strcat()'

Comment: I can't reproduce that. You probably have a problem with your input. As you never check anything, this can happen.

Comment: First print all of the variables by themselves. Or use a debugger.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: its working if i give other inputs!

Comment: This program is full of UB, `scanf("%s", ...)` will overflow **any** buffer. If `scanf()` fails, your program just continues, using the **uninitialized** values from your arrays.

Comment: Also don't use `strcat` in this manner.  Classic case of Schlemiel The Painter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm

Comment: So it doesn't like you personally :)

Comment: @Rahul your last edit is just nonsense, the issue is *indeed* a *buffer overflow*! See the one answer you got. And then stop using `scanf("%s", ...)`, it's the same crap as `gets()`. I recommend my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) btw.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but in `scanf(" %s",name);` the leading space in the format string is useless since the `%s` directive _automatically_ ignores leading whitespace characters. In fact, the only `scanf()` family directives that do not skip leading whitespace characters are `%c`, `%[]`, and `%n`.

Answer (score 7):

1rv16is038 is 10 characters, so you need 11 chars to store it plus the null terminator. The `usn` array is only 10 chars, so reading this into it is undefined behavior.

In general, you should avoid `scanf("%s", ...)` because there is no way to prevent buffer overflow. You can use `fgets` instead if you are reading separate lines, or limit the size with e.g. `scanf("%9s", ...)`.

Comment: but if you print usn then it is printing all the character

Comment: @Rahul That just means that it read past the end of the buffer when printing which is also undefined. Undefined behavior means things can go wrong in strange ways. Here it's probably overwriting other variables.

Comment: @Rahul learn what a buffer overflow **is**. C doesn't have range checks (or **any** runtime checks), just *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Rahul my test "worked", that is did not fail, and I didn't notice the buffer being too short. UB is not guaranteed to fail.